# No such file or directory error when using Hadoop fs --copyFromLocal command

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a local `VM` that has `Hortonworks` Hadoop and `hdfs` installed on it. I `ssh'ed` into the VM from my machine and now I am trying to copy a file from my local filesystem into hdfs through following set of commands:

```
[root@sandbox ~]# sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir /folder1/
[root@sandbox ~]# sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /root/folder1/file1.txt /hdfs_folder1/
```

When I execute it I get following error as - `copyFromLocal:/root/folder1/file1.txt': No such file or directory`

I can see that file right in `/root/folder1/` directory but with `hdfs` command its throwing above error. I also tried to `cd` to `/root/folder1/` and then execute the command but same error comes. Why is the file not getting found when it is right there?

Comment: Permissions? Usually only root is allowed to see what's in the `/root/` directory.

Comment: @Roman sorry I couldn't get by what you mean by that? I am trying to copy a fie from my local filesystem to hdfs. If I don't put `sudo -u hdfs` at the beginning then I get permission denied error

Answer (score 2):

By running `sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs...`, it tries to read the file /root/folder1/file.txt as hdfs.

You can do this.

1. Run `chmod 755 -R /root`. It will change permissions on directory and file recursively. But it is not recommended to open up permission on root home directory.
2. Then you can run the copyFromLocal as `sudo -u hdfs` to copy file from local file system to hdfs.

Better practice is to create user space for root and copy files directly as root.

1. `sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir /user/root`
2. `sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chown root:root /user/root`
3. hadoop fs -copyFromLocal

Comment: I did that but it still shows as `No such file or directory`. I executed `sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /root/folder1/file1.txt /hdfs_folder1/` after executing `chmod 755 -R /root/folder1`

Comment: the permission for this file is - `rwxrwxrwx 1 root root`

Comment: It is not just about file. You can run command `sudo -u hdfs ls -ltr /root/folder1` and see if it can list the file

Comment: I get pemission denied error. So what do I do? I changed the permission to 755 as you mentioned but still same issue

Comment: In that case you have to run this command `chmod 755 /root`, which is not advisable. You should not open up permissions on root directory. I have modified the answer to create user space for root and copy files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem running a Hortonworks 4 node cluster. As mentioned, user "hdfs" doesn't have permission to the root directory. The solution is to copy the information from the root folder to something the "hdfs" user can access. In the standard Hortonworks installation this is /home/hdfs

as root run the following...

> mkdir /home/hdfs/folder1
>
> cp /root/folder1/file1.txt /home/hdfs/folder1

now change users to hdfs and run from the hdfs USER's accessible directory

> su hdfs
>
> cd /home/hdfs/folder1

now you can access files as the hdfs user

> hdfs dfs -put file1.txt /hdfs_folder1