# How to move dataset into local HortonWorks HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-sandbox

I'm having trouble importing datasets u.data and u.item located in Downloads into HortonWorks Sandbox 2.1. I looked at [No such file or directory error when using Hadoop fs --copyFromLocal command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824396/no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-using-hadoop-fs-copyfromlocal-command) and tried the solution:

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir /user/Downloads
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chown Downloads:Downloads /user/Downloads
```

which did not produce error, although I'm not sure if it did anything.
Then

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /Downloads/u.data
```

led to No such file or directory error. How can this command be adjusted to import the datasets into the HortonWorks HDFS?

I'm logged in Jupyter Notebook through the IP address given by the local sandbox. But the user name is not shown and I don't think it is the default
'root'.
[image: Jupyter Notebook folders]

Comment: which user are you logged in as, seems like your username is Downloads which doesn't seem right.

Comment: @VikasSaxena Hi, appreciate your comment. I don't see an username. Typing IP address given by local sandbox asked for password or token. The default password of sandbox did not work so I logged in with the token from already used Jupyter notebook. Please see the updated post. It does not show username like 'root'. The two datasets are in Downloads and also uploaded in module2 folder. There is VirtualBox VMs folder that I believe was created after installing the sandbox.

Comment: You have a Hadoop user called `Downloads`? I'd suggest following a Hortonworks Sandbox tutorial on a clean instance - https://www.cloudera.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-hdp-sandbox.html is good and the first part is even about uploading data into HDFS https://www.cloudera.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-hdp-sandbox/2.html.

Comment: Your Jupyter instance is clearly running in Windows, and is likely not connected to your Hadoop VM instance at all. You need to use `scp` to move files between the two, not Jupyter or Windows File Explorer